# What approach to use when having similar method code but just have change in the caller name?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I am designing a class which is just wrapping a few methods calls which are part of another class library.

Here's what my class looks like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    IService Service; //Third Party Library.

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Initialization
    }

    public string MethodA()
    {
        Service.MethodA();
        return Service.GetResult();
    }

    public string MethodB()
    {
        Service.MethodB();
        return Service.GetResult();
    }

    public string MethodC()
    {
        Service.MethodC();
        return Service.GetResult();
    }

    public string MethodD()
    {
        Service.MethodD();
        return Service.GetResult();
    }
}
```

With the help of reflection I have refactored above code to some extent as below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    IService Service;

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Initialization
    }

    public string MethodA()
    {
       return GetResult(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    public string MethodB()
    {
       return GetResult(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    public string MethodC()
    {
       return GetResult(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    public string MethodD()
    {
       return GetResult(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private string GetResult(string methodName)
    {
       Service.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == methodName).Invoke(Service, null);
       return Service.GetResult();
    }
}
```

One drawback that I am seeing is that suppose if the library which am using release new version in the future and if there are any changes in the method name, it will not give any compilation error as I am using reflection, but at runtime, it will throw an exception.

Is there any better alternative solution to this approach?

Also, is there any way I can optimize my code further with/without reflection?

Comment: You could generate the code at compile time using things like T4 templates. As a bonus, this avoids the cost of reflection at runtime.

Comment: @JeroenMostert or even use [source generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) at build time

Comment: @JeroenMostert In't T4 template just for Web. I am trying to achieve this for console application using .Net Standard.

Comment: No, T4 is not just for web projects. It works in any project VS will run custom tooling in, including .NET Standard projects (in early versions there was no .NET Core support for T4, but that's since been implemented). Per phuzi, source generators are also an option as the Hot New Thing, though that may require a tooling upgrade (and the feature itself isn't final yet).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, but I am not sure how it's gonna help in this situation. I have just edited my questions if you can have a look again and want to update your answer as well accordingly.

Comment: A T4 template is just C# code generating C# code. It can load the library class at compile time, reflect over the methods of `IService` and generate a `MyClass` that wraps precisely those methods. If the library changes, the generated code will change with it, and you will get compile errors if other code relied on any of those methods. If you want to ensure things cannot break if the library is replaced as a binary in an already deployed application (i.e. no recompilation) that's another matter, but then runtime errors are of course unavoidable (unless you resort to `dynamic`).

Comment: Aside from compile-time generation, the usual tricks for speeding up reflection apply -- cache what you get (simple), use expression trees (slightly more complex), or generate IL at runtime (advanced). There is no need to call `GetMethods()` on every call, since the set of methods won't change at runtime. You can cache what you need in a static dictionary initialized in the static constructor. Instead of `GetCurrentMethod().Name` you can use `nameof`, and if you don't like typing the method name twice you could make a code snippet for it in VS.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, That seems to be a good approach. It would be helpful if you can share some code as well for having a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache the reflected `MethodInfo` into a `Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>` so you don't have to look it up every time you call `MyClass.GetResult(string methodName)`.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private string GetResult(string methodName)
   {
      if (!_methods.TryGetValue(methodName, out MethodInfo method))
      {
         method = typeof(IService).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == methodName);
         _methods.Add(methodName, method);
      }
      method.Invoke(Service, null);
      return Service.GetResult();
   }

   private static readonly Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> _methods = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();
}
```

Furthermore, you could eliminate the reflection in each of the public methods in `MyClass` by using the [`nameof` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string MethodA()
   {
      return GetResult(nameof(MethodA));
   }
}
```

Or course, if your third party dependency changes the name of a method then you still have a problem where that manifests itself as a runtime error instead of a compile time error. So, you could fix that by using `nameof` with the name of the method on `IService`.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string MethodA()
   {
      return GetResult(nameof(IService.MethodA));
   }
}
```

Now, if a method name on `IService` changes you get a compiler error.

This should be better optimized in terms of performance than your example. Except... what have you gained at this point? Each public method on `MyClass` still has to directly reference it's corresponding method on `IService`. I.E., `MyClass.MethodA` directly references `IService.MethodA`. So, why not just call `Service.MethodA` and save yourself the complexity and performance costs of reflection?

Furthermore, you're concerned about your third party dependency changing a method name and that creating runtime errors instead of compile time errors and the approach outlined here should address that. But, what if your third party dependency changes a method's signature? E.G., `IService.MethodA()` becomes `IService.MethodA(string param1)`? Now you're right back to square one with runtime exceptions instead of compiler errors.

I understand what you've posted is just an example, and that I can't understand the full context of what you're trying to do based on just an example. But, based on that example, in my opinion the best version of `MyClass` is the version *without* reflection. I'm really struggling to see what you gain by using reflection to call into `IService` rather than just calling the methods directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. ->  `why not just call Service. MethodA and save yourself the complexity and performance costs of reflection` - Actually, as you can see that in all the methods there are two code lines which are almost identical and at line 1 the only change is the method name, so I thought that might be a code smell and is there a better way to optimize it? I did cache all the methods and when I execute the code with/without reflection, performance is almost identical. So, is it better to go with `Service.MethodA` instead of reflection and keep the duplicate line in each method?

Comment: It's what I'd do. Just call, for example, `Service.MethodA` and `Service.GetResult` in `MyClass.MethodA` and follow that pattern for the rest of `MyClass`. Like you have in your example before the reflection refactoring. Others might feel differently, but I think the reflection is just additional complexity that doesn't add anything in this case. In any case, if you stick with reflection I'm glad the caching suggestion helped :).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with any of the two options you presented and add unit tests to verify if the version of the third-party library that is used for that particular build still has those methods in place. You can actually use some reflection and go quite deep with those unit tests, like, for example, checking if the method signatures are the same and so on. Those unit tests will guarantee you that your build will fail if those methods in the third-party library have changed.

Once the build passed (and all it's unit tests) there is no need to worry for the rest of it's lifetime.

P.S. Reflection is quite slow in general. If you choose the second option you might want to do a performance comparison between the first and the second option before implementing it. Having those unit tests means there's no need to use the second option.

P.S.2. I would have written a comment instead of a post but i don't have enough reputation

Comment: Thanks, but other than the compilation/runtime error, what I am looking to is for some code optimization as well with the above solution if there's any.

Comment: How about using a dictionary? Something like: MyClass.MethodD => Execute(CurrentMethodName)